# how to use php to check if a variable contains a group of characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex

i have a variable and i want to use php to check if it contains a **group of characters**
i would like the code to be like this

```
$groupofcharacters = ["$","#","*","("];
if($variable contains any of the letters in $groupofcharacters){
//do something}
```

i know that this will need the use of strpos() function but how can i use the strpos function to check if a variable contains a **group of characters** without me having to create a strpos() function for all the characters that i want to check for.

please if you don't understand you can tell me in the comments

Comment: Do you mean you want to check for any of the characters or that it contains all of the characters?

Comment: @NigelRen check if it contains any of the characters

Comment: Any update....?

Comment: @vivek_23  i wanted it to check a string if it contains atleast one of the characters

Comment: @vivek_23 i wanted the code to be something like this

Comment: @vivek_23                                                                                                                            if(variable contains ^ ){ do something}else{ if(variable contains *){do something} }

Comment: @vivek_23 but if i keep doing the above i might end up with a 100 lines of code

Comment: @webing Is the `do something` different for every character?

Comment: @vivek_23 no, ..

Comment: @webing Then the answers listed here do work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strpbrk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) to achieve this. The doc says:

> strpbrk — Search a string for any of a set of characters

> Returns a string starting from the character found, or FALSE if it is not found.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

if(strpbrk($variable,"$#*(") !== false){
   // your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve your issue is by using RegEx. Try this:

```
<?php
$variable = 'Any string containing $*(#';
$sPattern = '/[$#*(]/';

if (preg_match($sPattern, $variable)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: @vivek_23 what do you mean? I tested the code, and then posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

check if it has any char. Using strpos
First you need to combine the array as string after check ot if there's one of them in the

```
$groupofcharacters = ["$","#","*","("];
$strs = implode("", $groupofcharacters);

foreach(str_split($variable) as $s) {
   
   if (strpos($s, $strs)) {
      echo "it contains "; continue;
   }
}
```